# Python 3 - Reading html line by line and finding the right word

Tags: python

```
import urllib.request
url = "site.com"
request = urllib.request.Request(url)
my = urllib.request.urlopen(request)
print (my.read().decode('utf-8'))
```

I used this code, for example, to get the source code for lines 55 to 70 and then find a specific word in this section using if statements.

Comment: I...can't quite parse the English that's happening here. Can you clarify further?

Comment: 1-import html source code (optimal for get lines). 2-save to file.txt     3-find a tag in html source . can i clarifying ? thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
finding = '<sometag>'
text = my.read().decode('utf-8').splitlines()[54:70] # Include Line 55
pos = text.find(finding)
if pos != -1:
    # Do what you need to
```

Answer (score 2):

Get lines from 55 to 70:

```
lines = my.read().decode('utf-8').split("\n")[55:70]
```

Find something:

```
for line in lines:
    index = line.find(something)
    if index > -1:
        # ...
```

Then what you've find is in `line[index:index + len(something)]`.